# Reselect createSelector issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, reselect

Trying to use Redux's Reselect lib, like so:

```
// selectors.js
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const loggedIn = state => {
  return state.language.loggedIn;
};

export const loggedInSelector = createSelector(loggedIn);
```

And the usage like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { loggedInSelector } from "./../lib/selectors/language";

const Foo = ({ loggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Foo - {loggedIn ? "logged in" : "not logged in"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect(state => {
  console.log(state);
  const loggedIn = loggedInSelector(state);
  return {
    loggedIn
  };
})(Foo);
```

The result of the `console.log(state)` is:

```
language: {
  loggedIn: false
}
```

However, I receive a Type Error: cannot read property 'language' of undefined. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this, in my opinion, reasonably simple use case of Reselect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381318/redux-reselect-what-are-the-arguments-passed-to-create-selector-function

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed out in your own answer you are missing the transform function.

```
const getLoggedIn = state => state.language.loggedIn
export const getloggedInMemoized = createSelector(loggedIn, i => i)
```

The `cannot read property 'language' of undefined` error would relate to the initial state of your reducer function.

In your memoized selector the transform function is just the identity function `i => i` that’s a very strong indicator that the selector that you passed in (`const loggedIn = state => state.language.loggedIn`) did not need to be memoized. Why? Because `connect` of `react-redux` will internally do it’s own equality check to ensure that the component is only re-rendered if one or more of the props change.

Basically, your initial `loggedIn` selector is perfectly fine and there is no need for the extra overhead of `createSelector` (however small that is).

When to use `createSelector`?

1. *Anytime you are combining the result of two or more selectors*, as the syntax of `createSelector` really lends itself to building those selectors.
   eg.

   ```
   const taxSelector = createSelector(
     subtotalSelector,
     taxPercentSelector,
     (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
   )
   ```
2. *Anytime the selector is doing something computationally expensive*. `createSelector` will ensure that the transform function is only called if the result of at least one of the input selectors has changed.
3. And this is the subtle but key reason in my opinion. *When the return
   value of the selector is an `array` or an `object`*. This is very
   important for performance. The `connect` function of `react-redux`
   will perform a simple equality check of the props provided to see if
   the component needs to be re-rendered (expensive when it adds up).
   eg.

   ```
   const getSaleItems = state => {
     const items = getShopItems(state)
     return items.filter(i => i.isOnSale)
   }
   ```

   Every time `getSaleItems` is called it will return a new array. Even
   if the array returned by `getShopItems` has not changed. This means
   that `react-redux` will re-render the component because when it does
   a shallow equality check on the props provided it will see that the
   array has changed.

   On the other hand when using `createSelector`:

   ```
   const getSaleItems = createSelector(
     getShopItems,
     items => items.filter(i => i.isOnSale)
   }
   ```

   If the result of `getShopItems` has not changed successive calls to `getSaleItems` will return the same array instance because the result is memoized. This means that the shallow equality check
   of `react-redux` will see that nothing has changed and that it does
   not need to re-render the component .

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was missing the (seemingly required) second param to `createSelector`:

`export const loggedInSelector = createSelector(loggedIn, l => l);`

Comment: If I’m not misaken reselect memoizes the result based on params. In this case when returning `l => l` you don’t get any benefit from reselect. I’d use a normal selector.

Comment: 100%. Two questions: 1) Even if I don't get any benefit, are there any downsides to using Reselect for this? 2) When you say "normal selector" do you literally mean a function that accesses the state properties that I call from my `connect` function?

Comment: It has to be the other way round. `createSelector` takes one or more selectors and the memorized function as the last parameter. So: `createSelector(l => l, loggedIn)` would be correct.

Comment: @benhowdle89 There is not really any harm from it but also no benefit. Usually you use memorized selectors if the calculations inside them are heavy and should not be repeated every time when the result is known to be the same because the input did not change. In your case you are just returning a part of the state which is kind of already memorized.

Comment: @benhowdle89 I’d say if useless then remove it. And indeed i just meant simple function that access a part of the state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381318/redux-reselect-what-are-the-arguments-passed-to-create-selector-function